# Simple Triple Integral

Tags: matlab

I would expect an answer of 24, but it keeps showing me 72.

```
clc;clear all
F=@(x,y,z) x.*y.*z;
Mtotal = triplequad(F,0,2,0,4,0,3)
```

With or without the Dot Operator, I get the same thing.

Comment: Why do you expect 24?

Comment: You do realise `int(x)dx = (x^2)/2`, and not `x` right? Same holds in three dimensions, as @AndrasDeak points out in his answer, since they're independent variables.

Answer (score 3):

The answer *is* 72.

```
int int int (xyz) dx dy dz = (int x dx) (int y dy) (int z dz)
                           = (x^2)/2 (y^2)/2 (z^2)/2 + C
                           = (x^2 y^2 z^2)/8 + C
```

And:

```
>> prod(1/2*[2 4 3].^2)
ans =
    72
```

since the primitive function is zero at the lower boundaries, and so according to the Newton--Leibniz theorem, this is the only contribution left.

Comment: I plotted a 3D rectangle on a piece of paper; length*width*height =  2*4*3 = 24.  

I guess it's a product of the series.  Is that right?  I took Calc a very long time ago.  I guess I forgot a lot of that stuff.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ryguy72 what you computed is the *volume* of the integration domain, i.e. the integral of `f(x,y,z)=1`, a constant function. What you need to compute is simply a different function (along 1d it's not the area of a rectangle, but of a triangle). If you think my answer is sufficient, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: @ryguy72 if you think I've answered your question, please consider marking my answer as accepted.